# set min, max and default height of div relative to screen size

Tags: css

Is it possible to set `min`, `max` and `default` size of a `div` relative to the viewport size? Is this possible with nothing but CSS?

E.g.:

- the `div` should be at least `500px` tall
- the `div` should be at least `70vh` tall if `70vh` is not bigger than `850px`
- the `div` should be shorter than `850px`

Pseudo code (this is how it should work like)

```
min-height: max(70vh, 500px);
max-height: 850px;
```

Comment: Screen size is not viewport size, which one do you really mean?

Comment: @amn viewport size

Answer (score 0):

You can try Media Queries.

Simple sample: https://jsbin.com/coqayan/edit?html,output

```
<style>
.divSize{
    border:1px solid; 
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .divSize{
      border:1px solid #4286f4; 
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
    }
}
</style>

<div class="divSize">abc</div>
```

Comment: yes thats my current approach, but i was wondering if there is a better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can try combination of `height`, `min-height` and `max-height`:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}
.h {
  background-color: green;
  height: 70vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  max-height: 850px;
}
```

```html
<div class="h"></div>
```

Comment: i already tried this but then the div does not grow if the content is bigger than 70vh (it should grow until 850px)

Comment: @warch what's the size of your viewport? To get div `height` to `850px` it should be bigger than ~`1215px`. Try setting `200px` and `300px` as min and max size - and you'll see that `max-height` works as expected.